# Wordpress - Echo Value in Query_Posts

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

I need to echo a value inside a WordPress Query.  Here is my query first:

```
<?php if(have_posts()):?>
<?php query_posts('cat=14&posts_per_page=3');?>
<h1><?php echo get_the_category_by_id(14); ?></h1>
<?php the_content();?>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

The value I need to echo is this:  `<?php echo $tgh_first_category; ?>`

I need to echo this in place of where it says "14" - so I need to replace `cat=14` and `id(14)` with that echo.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I get this right you're basically unfamiliar with the primary PHP syntax rules? Then you should really read up with the documentation on [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php) to familiarize yourself with it.

As for your question, your code should become this:

```
<?php if(have_posts()):?>
<?php query_posts('cat=' . $tgh_first_category . '&posts_per_page=3');?>
<h1><?php echo get_the_category_by_id($tgh_first_category); ?></h1>
<?php the_content();?>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php endif;?>
```